# ZeroMQ pattern for dynamically registering handlers and routing specific requests to them

Tags: architecture, network-programming, ipc, zeromq

I have an application (sort of a program interpreter) for which I want to add the ability to define custom commands that are handled by separate processes over interprocess communication and/or tcp to another node.  These handlers are dynamic in the sense that some mechanism will register them at runtime (details to be determined), making the command they serve available to the core application.

The specific usage is to add extensibility to our application for customers to add their own features across process and network boundaries.  The interface between a single client and server to handle these requests is very simple:  a single outgoing request ("service this command") and a response (success, failure, specific error code).  Other interactions can be happening on different channels (handlers can call our API) but that's a separate set of problems.

Is there a well known ZeroMQ pattern for this kind of application?

Constraints:

1. Calls to handlers can be synchronous or asynchronous, depending on how they are specified at registration time, but in all cases a reply notifying of error will be handled within the main application
2. Handlers may handle just one or more types of calls, but there can be only one handler for any specific call type (ie, we need routing to explicit handlers, not a worker pool type paradigm where all handlers are equivalent)
3. Obviously the main application side needs to handle timeout, unresponsive handlers, etc
4. Syntax of calls to all handlers is always the same, the only issue is identifying handlers and routing requests to them.

**Concrete example**

- Main application
- Handler1 handles "makeWaffles" and "makePancakes" commands
- Handler2 handles "pourCoffee"
- ... arbitrary number of additional handlers

Main application parses a list of commands that you could think of as like a script, and when it receives a "makeWaffles" command, it looks up the identity of the handler for that command, makes sure the process itself is running*, transmits a request over a 0MQ socket, and aborts the execution if it receives an error in response (or if the handler is unresponsive / times out, etc).

- It may be desirable for handler processes not to be running and listening at all times, but to be started as needed to service requests which may or may not be present in any particular program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm toying with something similar, starting with the [Load Balancing Message Broker](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker) which maybe you can adapt to your needs, especially if you only ever have one 'client' you could do away with the broker component.

The key insight for me was the broker binds on ROUTER-typed frontend and backend sockets. Each server component connects a REQ socket to the backend (i.e they may come and go, since the broker maintains the 'well known' bind point) and sends a registration message.

Where the linked example just sends 'READY', I send a magic _REGISTER string, followed by the text of the command this server implements. I guess this could be a list of one server wants to implement a few related commands.

The broker gets these registration messages, and I keep a dict (I use mython, so pick your favourite hashmap here) mapping registered commands to the ID of the server who sent it. Because this came in on a ROUTER socket, you get the ID and followup empty part as the first two parts of the multipart message.

Then clients sent as normal on their REQ sockets. The broker gets them, complete with return address and uses the command to lookup the server (the 'load balancer' simply does a pop of available workers, I do the hash lookup and don't remove already registered workers).

The message gets wrapped in an envelope addressed to the correct server, and send on the backend socket for the server to receive and act upon.

When the server replies, the broker unwraps the enveloped addressed to itself, finding within a message addressed to the original requesting client, which gets sent as-is on the frontend socket.

With this right I'm able to have both clients and server components coming and going, and each server can implement a single command which gets routed towards it.

I'm not sure if this is in keeping with the Zen of ZMQ as a 'standard' pattern, but it works for me.

Future enhancements could be:

- Allow a server to register a list, rather than just one command to implement
- Deal with mis-behaving servers (keep-alives, timeouts, etc)
- If an unknown command is sent, the broker NAKs back directly to the client. I'm OK with the race here, but other logic might make better sense (i.e wait a little while for a late-registering server, etc)